# DirectX 11 Make a square.

Tags: c++, geometry, directx

So I'm following the tutorial from here http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut04.html on part 4. I'm trying to complete all the exercises before moving on to the next tutorial.

I've managed to do all of them except for changing the Triangle to a square.

At first I tried adding a fourth vertices for position and color and changing the fourth to draw the last corner and the middle tip (as it is created in the tutorial) to be the top right, following the clockwise rule  of drawing them. That didn't work so I recalled that shapes must be drawn using triangles, so I opted to try using two triangles. The first draws as expected and the second draws as expected, each completing half of a square, but I can't get them both to draw at the same time.

I made sure to draw them clockwise and added enough indexes to accomodate all vertices and it just won't draw them both to make a square. Am I missing something? Here is the function I am working in.

```
      bool ModelClass::InitializeBuffers(ID3D11Device* device)
    {
VertexType* vertices;
unsigned long* indices;
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc, indexBufferDesc;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexData, indexData;
HRESULT result;


// Set the number of vertices in the vertex array.
m_vertexCount = 6;

// Set the number of indices in the index array.
m_indexCount = 6;

// Create the vertex array.
vertices = new VertexType[m_vertexCount];
if(!vertices)
{
    return false;
}

// Create the index array.
indices = new unsigned long[m_indexCount];
if(!indices)
{
    return false;
}

// Load the vertex array with data.

vertices[0].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);  // Bottom left.
vertices[0].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

vertices[1].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Top left.
vertices[1].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

vertices[2].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // top right.
vertices[2].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

vertices[3].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);  // Bottom left.
vertices[3].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

vertices[4].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // top right.
vertices[4].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

vertices[5].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);  // Bottom right.
vertices[5].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

// Load the index array with data.
indices[0] = 0;  // Bottom left.
indices[1] = 1;  // Top left.
indices[2] = 2;  // top right.

indices[3] = 0;  // Bottom left.
indices[4] = 1;  // Top left.
indices[5] = 2;  // top right.
// Set up the description of the static vertex buffer.
    vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VertexType) * m_vertexCount;
    vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
vertexBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;

// Give the subresource structure a pointer to the vertex data.
    vertexData.pSysMem = vertices;
vertexData.SysMemPitch = 0;
vertexData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

// Now create the vertex buffer.
    result = device->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexData, &m_vertexBuffer);
if(FAILED(result))
{
    return false;
}

// Set up the description of the static index buffer.
    indexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    indexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(unsigned long) * m_indexCount;
    indexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    indexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    indexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
indexBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;

// Give the subresource structure a pointer to the index data.
    indexData.pSysMem = indices;
indexData.SysMemPitch = 0;
indexData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

// Create the index buffer.
result = device->CreateBuffer(&indexBufferDesc, &indexData, &m_indexBuffer);
if(FAILED(result))
{
    return false;
}

// Release the arrays now that the vertex and index buffers have been created and loaded.
delete [] vertices;
vertices = 0;

delete [] indices;
indices = 0;

return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close, but your index buffer isn't right.  Since you've defined your second triangle as vertices 3, 4, and 5, your indices need to match:

```
indices[0] = 0;  // Bottom left.
indices[1] = 1;  // Top left.
indices[2] = 2;  // top right.

indices[3] = 3;  // Bottom left.
indices[4] = 4;  // Top left.
indices[5] = 5;  // top right.
```

Alternatively, since you're already using DrawIndexed, you can eliminate duplicate vertices:

```
vertices[0].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);  // Bottom left.
vertices[0].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

vertices[1].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Top left.
vertices[1].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

vertices[2].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // top right.
vertices[2].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

vertices[3].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);  // Bottom right.
vertices[3].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

// Load the index array with data.
indices[0] = 0;  // Bottom left.
indices[1] = 1;  // Top left.
indices[2] = 2;  // top right.

indices[3] = 0;  // Bottom left.
indices[4] = 2;  // Top right.
indices[5] = 3;  // Bottom right.
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you.